# Django-form is not bounded when used __init__ to create fields

Tags: python, django, forms, django-forms, django-views

I used **init** method to create a ChoiceField in the form in order to call another function which populates the choices of the field. Now when the user selects the dropdown and submits the form, I cannot successfully create the form with the request, and I'm thinking "bound=False" is making the form invalid. Is there a way to use the **init** method to create form fields while making the form valid when passed in **request.POST**? Thanks in advance.

Forms.py

```
class CoursesForm(forms.Form):

    def __init__(self, subject, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CoursesForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['course'] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=get_uw_courses_from_subject(subject), required=False)
```

View.py: the method that handles the **submitted** form

```
def display_selection(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        course_form = CoursesForm(request.POST) # <CourseForm bound=False...>

        if course_form.is_valid():  # Not valid here
            selected_course = course_form.cleaned_data['course']
    else:
        pass
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you've overridden the method signature so that the first positional argument is `subject`, not `data`. *Don't do that*.

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    subject = kwargs.pop('subject', None)
    ...
```

Also, don't forget to actually *pass* the subject argument:

```
course_form = CoursesForm(request.POST, subject=whatever)
```